# Prove that $\sum {y_n^2}$ is absolutely convergent, if $\sum {z_n^2}$ is convergent

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Let $\left\{ {{z_n}} \right\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers, with $\operatorname{Re} \left( {{z_n}} \right) \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let ${z_n} = {x_n} + i{y_n}$, and given that the series $\sum {{z_n}}$ is convergent, and $\sum {z_n^2}$ is also convergent, prove that prove that $\sum {y_n^2}$ is absolutely convergent.

Previous to this I proved that $\sum {x_n^2}$ is absolutely convergent, and $\sum {{x_n}{y_n}}$ is absolutely convergent as well, so I could use these facts.

I know that since $\sum {z_n^2}  = \sum {\left( {x_n^2 + 2i\;{x_n}{y_n} - y_n^2} \right)}$ is convergent, then $\sum {y_n^2}$ is convergent. This means $\left\{ {y_n^2} \right\} \to 0$. Then for any $\varepsilon  > 0$ we have $\left| {y_n^2} \right| < \varepsilon$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How would I proceed from here? Or maybe I'm off track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y_n^2 \ge 0$, so if $\sum y_n^2$ is convergent it's absolutely convergent.